# Help identifying a part for a rider mower (picture)

Tags: lawn-mower

I have had a renter at my home who left some items behind in my shed. One of them is the item shown which I believe is a rear attachment for a rider mower.  It does not fit mine.  Can anyone help identify what this is?

[image: Unidentified Rider Mower rear attachment]

[image: Unidentified Rider Mower rear attachment opposite side]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a quick-attach unit for a garden tractor of some kind. For some implements such as snow blowers or blades which are only required for some seasons and the user wants to be able to load and unload the implement without leaving the driver seat. You might have better luck finding what make of tractor at one of the tractor-specific sites.

Comment: Asked on another site, got a hit on that identified one of the parts as Cub Cadet (my pictures are upside down from how it's normally used).  It's this: https://www.partswarehouse.com/Cub-Cadet-190-670-100-Twin-Rear-Bagger-Kit-s/380618.htm